# How do I select only the most recent record based on a userid that can be in either of two columns?

Tags: mysql, unique, messaging, message

I have a `messages` table that is structured somewhat like this:

```
from  |  to  |  date
-----------------------------------
1     |  3   |  2011-09-23 11:51:44
3     |  1   |  2011-09-23 11:56:29
3     |  2   |  2011-10-04 10:20:01
2     |  3   |  2011-10-05 07:48:00
```

I want to display a messages page on my website very similar to Facebook's messages page, which shows a list of the people with which the user has a conversation. Regardless of the depth of the conversation, the page only shows each person once, along with the most recent message in that conversation with that particular person, whether it was sent *or* received.

The part that stumps me is that the most recent message can be either sent or received, which means that the user's ID number can be in either the `from` or `to` column. I'm not sure how to test against both columns the way I need to.

I'm still learning how to write more complex MySQL queries, and while I feel like this is a simple case of using `OR` with subqueries, I can't seem to get it right.

**SOLUTION**
Turns out it wasn't really a very simple case at all.  Widor took some time to help me out with this, and the following query finally seems to do the job.  It hasn't been tested thoroughly, but so far it seems to work fine:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   messages m
       JOIN (SELECT Max(x.id)      AS `id`,
                    x.userid,
                    x.partnerid,
                    Max(x.mostrecent) AS `mostrecent`
             FROM  (SELECT Max(id)     `id`,
                           `from`         AS `userid`,
                           `to`           AS `partnerid`,
                           Max(`created`) AS `mostrecent`
                    FROM   messages
                    GROUP  BY `from`,
                              `to`
                    UNION
                    SELECT Max(id)     `id`,
                           `to`           AS `userid`,
                           `from`         AS `partnerid`,
                           Max(`created`) AS `mostrecent`
                    FROM   messages
                    GROUP  BY `to`,
                              `from`) AS `x`
             GROUP  BY x.`userid`,
                       x.`partnerid`) AS `y`
         ON y.id = m.id
WHERE  y.userid = $userid
```

Comment: Nowt wrong with this question :-)

Comment: you can join the table with itself, on from = to, and count the distinct date

Comment: Aside from the thanks and tags in the title...

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the outcome? This is a bit of a "do it for me" question.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, I understand what you mean.  The thing is, I tried several different things very quickly over a short period of time, and when something doesn't work, I don't make a point to make a note of it, so I don't really remember everything I tried.  I will try to be more thorough next time.

Comment: @vertigoelectric: You should re-create that process when formulating the question, if you didn't record things the first time around. It's not too late to edit it in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RE-EDITED**

My previous answer (as some other ones here) didn't take account of the case where you have more than 2 conversation 'partners', which isn't the case in your example data but I'm sure will be in real life.

So consider the case where you now have an extra record in the data:

```
1    |     4    | 2011-10-04 08:34:12
```

My revised query is as follows:

```
SELECT userid, partnerid, max(mostRecent) from (
    SELECT [from] as [userid], [to] as [partnerid], max([date]) as [mostrecent] FROM messages GROUP BY [from], [to]
    UNION 
    SELECT [to] as [userid], [from] as [partnerid],max([date]) as [mostrecent] FROM messages GROUP BY [to], [from]
) [x]
WHERE userid = ?
GROUP BY userid, partnerid
```

So, our inner `UNION` gives us a dataset containing the `userid` along with a `partnerid`, i.e. who they are chatting to. This could be created separately as a view if you wanted, to simplify the query.

The outer `SELECT` then retrieves one record for every 'partner' that the specified `userid` has had a chat with, along with the most recent date.

The `Max()` function achieves the most recent date, and the `GROUP BY` takes care of ensuring we bring back more then one record for each partner.

Comment: Actually, just realised you don't need extra data in the example. `3` talks to `1` and `2` and should therefore have 2 records returned.

Comment: That's a very important point and I completely overlooked it.  There WOULD be multiple people you would have conversations with.  Just makes it more complex for me.  I'll try your query and let you know how it works for me.

Comment: At first I didn't realize that I had to change your [] brackets to ``.  Anyway, I got it to return results successfully, but I failed to mention a very important part of all this.  I need to be able to retrieve the entire row, not just those columns we're using to find them.  I apologizing for forgetting to mention that part.

Comment: Oops, looks like there's a lot of misreading going on - I used SQl Server notation, not my SQL! Anyway, I'll edit my post to show you how to retrieve the entire row, but do you have a Primary Key on the table?

Comment: Looks like I was able to just add a few * here and there to pull all the columns.  There is a problem though.  For some reason, this isn't retrieving the most recent messages.  It's retrieving the oldest.

Comment: @vertigoelectric Are you sure? If I choose `3` as the parameter, I get 2 records - one for `1` at 11:56:29 on 23rd and another for `2` at 07:48:00 on the 5th?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I didn't see your question about Primary Key.  Yes there is a Primary Key.  A column named `id` (which would be the id for the message, not a user).  I'll come back in a little bit to see your revised MySQL version of the query :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4205/discussion-between-vertigoelectric-and-widor)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
SELECT MAX(date), * FROM messages WHERE to IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT to FROM messages WHERE from = :id
) GROUP BY to
UNION
SELECT MAX(date), * FROM messages WHERE from IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT from FROM messages WHERE to = :id
) GROUP BY from
ORDER BY 1
```

Where `id` is the parameter you're using for the user ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a view and query it:

```
CREATE VIEW dataview AS 
(SELECT t1.from AS userid, t1.date FROM messages AS t1) 
UNION
(SELECT t2.to AS userid, t2.date FROM messages AS t2)
```

look at the result table, it should now be very easy to query what you want

Answer (score -1):

I think you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM messages
WHERE from = $userid
   OR to   = $userid
```

You would replace `$userid` with the actual value, hopefully using [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).  :-)